# Stack Machine Emulator Scala

Tags: scala, stack, pattern-matching, emulation

Here I have a final function which should execute foldLeft on a list of instructions. I'm getting

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (List[Double], scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double])
 required: Map[String,Double]
            instructionList.foldLeft(Nil : List[Double], Map.empty[String,Double])((acc:(List[Double], Map[String,Double]), SMI:StackMachineInstruction) => {
```

I'm not sure if I'm initializing the accumulator correctly

```
def emulateStackMachine(instructionList: List[StackMachineInstruction]): Map[String, Double] =
        {
            instructionList.foldLeft((Nil : List[Double], Map.empty[String,Double]))((acc:(List[Double], Map[String,Double]), SMI:StackMachineInstruction) => {
                emulateSingleInstruction(acc._1, acc._2, SMI)
            })
        }
```

Comment: @jwvh hey! thanks for help on the other question dude. Similar to the other solution, I'm actually getting the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't creating a tuple but passing values as if it was two parameter call. Use either:

```
((Nil : List[Double], Map.empty[String,Double])) // double parens
```

or

```
(List.empty[Double] -> Map.empty[String,Double]) // -> syntax
```

to create a tuple and pass it into a call.

Additionally you have to change you output type - it's

```
Map[String, Double]
```

while value returned by the function is:

```
(List[Double], Map[String,Double])
```

```
def emulateStackMachine(instructionList: List[StackMachineInstruction]): (List[Double], Map[String, Double]) = {
  instructionList.foldLeft(List.empty[Double] -> Map.empty[String,Double])((acc, SMI) => {
    emulateSingleInstruction(acc._1, acc._2, SMI)
  })
}
// or
def emulateStackMachine(instructionList: List[StackMachineInstruction]): Map[String, Double] = {
  instructionList.foldLeft(List.empty[Double] -> Map.empty[String,Double])((acc, SMI) => {
    emulateSingleInstruction(acc._1, acc._2, SMI)
  })._2
}
```

Comment: That makes complete sense. Surprisingly, I'm getting the same error message

Comment: Also change the output type.

Comment: I see your edit. That compiles correctly but now I have ```found   : Map[String,Double]
 required: (List[Double], scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double])
                emulateSingleInstruction(acc._1, acc._2, smi)._2 ```

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LWNw54bASgOlKCGTEsdGJA

Comment: While you're available do you have a one line solution for a LoadI and StoreI? Here is where I'm at ```case class LoadI(s: String) extends StackMachineInstruction```
```case class  StoreI(s: String) extends StackMachineInstruction ``` ```case LoadI(s) => ...```  ```case StoreI(s) => ... ```