# Scala Machine Emulator

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, load, emulation, store

I'm building a stack machine emulator and I'm having trouble figuring out how to update an environment/map in both Load and Store cases. My goals here are figuring out how to update a map and also iterating to get the correct value to be used to update a map.

```
case class LoadI(s: String) extends StackMachineInstruction
case class  StoreI(s: String) extends StackMachineInstruction
```

```
    def emulateSingleInstruction(stack: List[Double],
                                 env: Map[String, Double],
                                 ins: StackMachineInstruction): (List[Double], Map[String, Double]) = {
        ins match{
            case AddI => stack match{
                case i1 :: i2 :: tail => (i1 + i2 :: tail, env)
                case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
            }
            case PushI(f) => (f :: stack,env)

            //broken
            case LoadI(s) => stack match {
                case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
                case i1 :: tail => (tail,env) match {
                    case (top,env) => (top, env + s -> top ) // Not clear on how to update an environment
                }
            }
            //broken
            case StoreI(s) => stack match {
                case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
                case i1 :: tail => // Need to take the value that s maps to in the environment. Let the value be v. Push v onto the top of the stack.
            }

            case PopI => stack match{
                case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
                case i1 :: tail => {
                    (tail,env)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is an example of a test case I have in a different file

```
test("stack machine test 3") {
        val lst1 = List(PushI(3.5), PushI(2.5), PushI(4.5), PushI(5.2), AddI, LoadI("x"), LoadI("y"), LoadI("z"), StoreI("y"), LoadI("w"))
        val fenv = StackMachineEmulator.emulateStackMachine(lst1)
        assert(fenv contains "x")
        assert(fenv contains "y")
        assert(fenv contains "z")
        assert( math.abs(fenv("x") - 9.7 ) <= 1e-05 )
        assert( math.abs(fenv("y") - 2.5 ) <= 1e-05 )
        assert( math.abs(fenv("z") - 3.5 ) <= 1e-05 )
    }
```

Comment: This code is referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331351/stack-machine-emulator-scala/64331413 but it's still too little to tel which variable is which, what they are supposed to do, etc. Please show more complete example where this pattern matching is performed.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I just made an edit to show the complete emulator. Does this help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your question about how to implement a stack machine or how to use Maps in scala? Why conflate both things?

Comment: @pedrofurla I'm more concerned on implementing the stack machine. Good point, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.updated` to update a map. Or add a tuple, but Scala has to know that something is a tuple (`map + a -> b` is seen as `(map + a) -> b`, so you have to use `map + (a -> b)`).

You can use `.get`, .`getOrElse` or `.apply` to extract value from map. They will: return `Option`, returns value or default value on missing, or extract value or throw if missing. So the last one kind of requires checking.

If you also remember that patterns can be composed in pattern matching you can write your interpreter as:

```
def emulateSingleInstruction(stack: List[Double],
                             env: Map[String, Double],
                             ins: StackMachineInstruction): (List[Double], Map[String, Double]) =
  (ins, stack) match {
    case (AddI, i1 :: i2 :: tail)          => ((i1 + i2) :: tail) -> env
    case (PushI(f), _)                     => (f :: stack) -> env
    case (LoadI(s), i1 :: tail)            => tail -> env.updated(s, i1)
    case (StoreI(s), _) if env.contains(s) => (env(s) :: stack) -> env
    case (PopI, _ :: tail)                 => tail -> env
    case _                                 => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  }
```

Comment: Okay so this work, but I'm getting value update is not a member of Map[String,Double]. I have the following:  ```case LoadI(s) => stack match {
     case Nil => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
                case i1 :: tail => s -> env.update(s, i1)
                } ```

Comment: Thanks man! I'm using the full version of IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: As it stands I'm getting ```type mismatch;
found   : (String, scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Double])
required: (List[Double], Map[String,Double])
            case (LoadI(s), i1 :: tail) => s -> env.updated(s, i1)
 ```

Comment: Try now, I've fixed small mistake

Comment: Everything works perfectly. I'm getting a runtime error but I'm going to debug that now.